# How can I name to a saved file with the numerical values of some specific parameters?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, string-manipulation, save, data-format

I'm using some parameters to determine the elements of a list. I want to save this list with DumpSave, but I need to name it with its parameters.
For example, I use the following parameters

`>a=1;`

`>b=5;`

`c=12;`

and the list is determined by

`Q=Table[f[i,j,k],{i,a},{j,b},{k,c}];(*this is just an example*)`

Then, I want to save Q with DumpSave in the following way

> `DumpSave["1-5-12.mx",{Q}](*of the form "a-b-c.mx"*)`

and then, it would be opened with,

`<<DumpSave[1-5-12.mx]`

I want to automatize the saved process. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 1;
b = 5;
c = 12;

(* version 10 *)
StringTemplate["`1`-`2`-`3`.mx"][a, b, c]
(* "1-5-12.mx" *)

(* 10 and lower *)
StringJoin @@ Riffle[ToString /@ {a, b, c}, "-"] <> ".mx"
(* "1-5-12.mx" *)
```